# Calculate Multivariable limits with sympy

Tags: python, math, sympy

How do you calculate multivariable limits in `sympy`?

I'm trying to find the limit of the following equation
`exp = (x**2-64)*cos(1/(x-8)**2+(y-8)**2)` as x and y tend to 8.

My code looks like this:

```py
x, y = symbols("x y")
exp = (x**2-64)*cos(1/(x-8)**2+(y-8)**2)

exp.subs(x,8).subs(y,8)
```

`Sympy` is returning `0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `limit` rather than `subs` if you want to compute a limit.

```
In [42]: (sin(x)/x).subs(x, 0)
Out[42]: nan

In [43]: (sin(x)/x).limit(x, 0)
Out[43]: 1
```

Note that a multivariable limit is not well defined in general. You need to specify the order you want to take the limits in or otherwise give some relationship between `x` and `y` because the limit depends on how `x` and `y` approach `8` when you take the limit. This is particularly important in a case like this where you have something like `cos(1/x**2)` which gives an essential singularity at the limit.

```
In [44]: exp.limit(y, 8).limit(x, 8)
Out[44]: <-128, 128>

In [45]: exp.limit(x, 8).limit(y, 8)
Out[45]: 0
```

The last result there is due to

```
In [64]: exp.limit(x, 8)
Out[64]: 0
```

which is a valid result for any value of `y` except `8`. Taking the limits in reverse order gives you the result of the `x` limit when `y` is equal to `8`.

Which of those you want or whether you actually wanted something else depends on your application because there isn't a unique answer to the question as posed.

Comment: Actually looking closer maybe the limits shown above for `exp` should all be zero...